# SPI on ADE7953 board

Tags: arduino, spi

So, I've been trying to emplement a SPI communication between the board and my arduino. In the board's manual, it says that it is required to send two bytes with the address I want to read/write and another byte to choose read or write (most significant bit tells you which will apply). However, my code does not seem to be running. Anyone care to help? [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOzY5.png)

Comment: Please post you code in your question, not attaching image.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the actual Arduino SPI library, but I will offer you an Arduino snippet that will bitbang SPI instead.  It will allow you to send some bytes just to see if everything is working.  It might be useful to try another approach just to see if it works.  You will need to change the pins and registers to match your target application.

```
#define PIN_SPIDATA 16
#define PIN_SPICLK  17
#define PIN_SPILOAD 18

#define REG_DECODEMODE  0x09
#define REG_INTENSITY   0x0A
#define REG_SCANLIMIT   0x0B
#define REG_SHUTDOWN    0x0C
#define REG_DISPLAYTEST 0x0F

void setup() {

  // set ddr for sw spi pins
  pinMode(PIN_SPICLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_SPIDATA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_SPILOAD, OUTPUT);

  setRegister(REG_INTENSITY, 0x04); 
  setRegister(REG_SCANLIMIT, 0x07);
  setRegister(REG_SHUTDOWN, 0x01);    // normal operation
  setRegister(REG_DECODEMODE, 0x00);  // pixels not integers
  setRegister(REG_DISPLAYTEST, 0x00); // not in test mode
}

// sends a single byte by sw spi (no latching)
void putByte(uint8_t data)
{
  uint8_t i = 8;
  uint8_t mask;
  while(i > 0) {
    mask = 0x01 << (i - 1);         // get bitmask
    digitalWrite(PIN_SPICLK, LOW);   // tick
    if (data & mask){               // choose bit
      digitalWrite(PIN_SPIDATA, HIGH); // set 1
    }else{
      digitalWrite(PIN_SPIDATA, LOW);  // set 0
    }
    digitalWrite(PIN_SPICLK, HIGH);  // tock
    --i;                            // move to lesser bit
  }
}

// sets register to the same byte value for all screens
void setRegister(uint8_t reg, uint8_t data)
{
  digitalWrite(PIN_SPILOAD, LOW); // begin
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < numChips; ++i){
    putByte(reg);  // specify register
    putByte(data); // send data
  }
  digitalWrite(PIN_SPILOAD, HIGH);  // latch in data
  digitalWrite(PIN_SPILOAD, LOW); // end
}
```